# Propagating Exceptions from Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, exception, task

In the following program, how do I propagate the OverflowException to Main?

```
class Program
{
    static readonly CancellationTokenSource Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallDoSomething(1);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void CallDoSomething(int foo)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(foo), Source.Token);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var result = task.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            CallDoSomething(result);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);

        task.ContinueWith(t => t.Exception?.Handle(ex => throw ex), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    static int DoSomething(int foo)
    {
        if (foo > 100)
        {
            Source.Cancel();
            throw new OverflowException("foo overflowed");
        }

        return foo * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use async\await? Then this code will be _much_ more simple (including exceptions propagation).

Comment: Yes, but I'm hoping to have to avoid that since this means I have to change existing, working code that is written in this way all over the place.  This is just a toy example.  The change request involves handling Exceptions higher up.

Comment: Ok, then need to clarify what you mean with propagate to `Main`. Exception is thrown in another thread, and thread in Main is doing other things at the moment exception is thrown (blocked on `Console.Read` in this case) - how would you expect such propagation to work?

Comment: The are several options of course, including writing an ExceptionHandler that is called when an exception is encountered.  Another is to set some flag on the callee (as I said, this is just a toy example) and have it monitored elsewhere.  I'm asking here because it seems like it is something people must have come across before...

Comment: If you dont want to start propagating your `async` methods, meaning that you will use all in an synchronous manner, you may need to `.Wait()` for a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` to complete. After waiting, you can access to all of it's properties, including Exceptions.

Comment: If you have a lot of continuations and cannot return `Task` itself from `CallDoSomethin` so that caller can wait on it - consider using `TaskCompletionSource`.